# Disabling copying in dojo.dnd

Tags: dojo, drag-and-drop, dojo-dnd

By default a dojo.dnd.Source container allows you to hold Ctrl to duplicate/copy a dragged item rather than just move it.

I know you can set singular=true to stop multiple items being dragged but how do I stop copying? Duplicating items makes no sense in the context of my items (I am making a draggable list for reordering pages on a website menu).

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm unsure if there's a nicer way, but I've always accomplished this by clobbering the `copyState` method on the Source instance to always return `false`.

If you've got several Sources on the page, you could also elect to `dojo.declare` a subclass with the method overridden, or `dojo.extend` `dojo.dnd.Source` itself to clobber the method in all instances.

Comment: Incidentally this is the officially approved method. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Or second option

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){

    //Disable the key events Ctrl and Shift
    dojo.extend( dojo.dnd.Source, { copyState: function( keyPressed, self ){ 
        return false; }}
    );

    //Create the dnd source object for data point column bar
    columnBar = new dojo.dnd.Source("viewColumnBar",{ singular: true });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Ken Franquiero, I managed to solve this problem. For others in the same boat, here's my code:

```
/**
 * Extend dojo.dnd.Source to prevent copying
 */

dojo.require( 'dojo.dnd.Source' );
dojo.addOnLoad( function() {

    dojo.declare
    (
        'EditPosition',
        dojo.dnd.Source,
        {
            copyState: function( keyPressed, self )
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    );

    oEditPosition = new EditPosition
    ( 
        'position_container', 
        {
            withHandles: 'true'
        } 
    );

} );
```

HTML:

```
<div id="position_container">
    <div class="dojoDndItem">
        <div class="dojoDndHandle drag_icon drag_handle"></div> <strong>Short Paragraphs</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="dojoDndItem">
        <div class="drag_icon fixed_handle"></div> About Us
    </div>
    <div class="dojoDndItem">
        <div class="drag_icon fixed_handle"></div> Team Members
    </div>
</div>
```